# Cosmos DB with multiple partition keys

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We're looking at potentially using a **single Cosmos DB collection** to hold **multiple document types** in a **multi-tenanted environment** using a **tenant ID as the partition key**. The ***path to tenant id may change in each document type*** and I am therefore looking at various was of exposing the partition key to Cosmos DB to enable correct partitioning / querying.

I have noticed that the Paths property of DocumentCollection.PartitionKey is a collection and was therefore wondering whether it is possible to pass multiple paths during the creation of a document collection and what the behaviour of this might be. Ideally, I would like Cosmos to scan each of these paths and use the first value or aggregate of values as the partition key but cannot find any documentation suggesting that this is indeed the behaviour.

The [MSDN documentation for this property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.partitionkeydefinition.paths?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_PartitionKeyDefinition_Paths) is pretty useless and none of the [associated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data) [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips) seems to answer the question. Does anyone know about or previously used multiple partition key paths in a collection?

To be clear, I'm looking for links to additional documentation about and/or direct experience of the Cosmos DB's behaviour when specifying multiple partition keys in the PartitionKey.Paths collection when creating a DocumentCollection.

This question has also been posted in the [Azure Community Support forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d7113e26-f814-4e7d-bd52-9bee3dc70511/cosmos-db-with-multiple-partition-keys?forum=windowsazuredata).

Thanks, Ian

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to assign a generic partition key like “pk”, then assign this value based on each of your object types. You can for example, manage this during serialization by having different properties for each class to be serialized to “pk”.

The reason partition key is an array in DocumentCollection.PartitionKey is to allow us to introduce compound partition keys, where the combination of multiple properties like (“firstName”, “lastName”) form the partition key. This is a little different from what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately this new partition key would not be included in the queries we’re running (we’d use the tenant id within the specific document type) meaning the query would – I believe - be sent across multiple partitions, potentially increasing the cost of the query

Comment: You can force the query to execute for a partition key by setting FeedOptions.PartitionKey (x-ms-documentdb-partition-key in REST) if you know this based on Object type in code

Answer (score 3):

Further to the above, I ended up adding a partition key property to the document container as suggested by Aravind and then used [David Fowler's](https://github.com/davidfowl) excellent [QueryInteceptor](https://github.com/davidfowl/QueryInterceptor) [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QueryInterceptor/) to apply an [ExpressionVisitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) which translated any equivalence expression relating to the specific document type's tenant id property into a equivalence expression on the partition key property. This ensured that queries would be performed against only the single, correct partition. Furthermore, I was able to use the ExpressionVisitor as a safety feature in that it is able to enforce that all queries provide a filter on tenant id (as, obviously, tenants should never be able to see each others documents) and if none has been specified then no records are returned (an invalid equivalence expression is added to the partition key property).

This has been tested and seems to be working well.